# Let bindings to one function

Tags: function, binding, f#, tuples, let

So, I can't figure out how you make 2 let bindings to the same function result (tuple) in FSharp. For example, if I have a function:
**Play()** whose output is **(x,y)**.
And i wanna use x and y in another function. Right now I write:

```
Let first = fst Play()
Let second = snd Play().
```

But this 2 let bindings are just running function twice.
So if it makes sense, how do I make 2 let bindings to a function, that only have to run once? :D
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
let first, second = Play()
```

You could also bind the tuple and later separate it:

```
let coords = Play()
let x      = fst coords
let y      = snd coords
```